# Как мне сделать так чтоб прошлое окно закрылось и новое появилось в python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, password

есть код и я не могу сделать так чтобы закрылось прошлое окно и открылось новое
КОД:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import getpass
import sys
import os
import os.path
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()

#НАСТРАИВАЕМ ОКНО
tk = Tk()
tk["bg"] = 'steel blue'
tk.title("VbacksREGEN by postik")
tk.geometry("500x140+700+400")
tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)


def vesti():
    P = nk.get()  # получаем Entry

    if P == '123':
        messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'Correct password!')
        tk.quit()

    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Invalid password')


nkt = Label(text='V-backs generator', foreground='white',   background="steel blue", font=('Courier 25'))
nkt.pack()



nk = Entry(bg='white', show="*", font='20')
nk.pack()

nkw = Label(text='password', foreground='white',   background="steel blue", font=('Courier 15'))
nkw.pack()

btn1 = Button(text="Enter", background="white", foreground="steel blue",
              padx="20", pady="8", font="16", command=vesti)
btn1.pack()



tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо добавить в импорт пакет с диалоговыми окнами:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

И из этого импорта выберете один:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
```

По поводу перехода на следующую страницу, читайте мой пост [Как перейти с одной страницы на другую в приложении?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1396682/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/1396712#1396712)

Закрытие основного окна Ткинтер приведет к выходу из приложения. Если оно вам больше не нужно, то его или сворачивают или прячут.